# How to programmatically fetch a list of applications from the Software Center

Tags: software-center, python, application-development

Im writing a PyGI app where I'd like to show a list of matching applications from the Ubuntu Software Centre in an auto-completion text entry or dropdwon. I haven't yet figured out the best way to present the information, I just want to make it easier for the user to type the name of an application.

But before that, I'd like to figure out how to get the data. Is there an API to get a list of all applications from the Software Centre, or indirectly through the Applications Dash in Unity?

Comment: See also http://askubuntu.com/questions/112004/is-there-any-web-api-for-software-center-available for the web API

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the xapian DB directly:

```
import xapian
db=xapian.Database("/var/cache/software-center/xapian")
for m in db.postlist(""): 
    appname = db.get_document(m.docid).get_data()
```

Or the internal software-center API:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, "/usr/share/software-center/")
import softwarecenter.db.database
db = softwarecenter.db.database.StoreDatabase()
db._aptcache.open()
# 'use_axi' is use apt-xapian-index
# 'use_agent' is use the Software Center Agent database
db.open(use_axi=False, use_agent=False)
for doc in db:
    app = db.get_application(doc)
    print app.appname, app.pkgname
    appdetails = app.get_details(db)
    # Icon names are relative to /usr/share/app-install/icons/
    print appdetails.icon
```

Comment: Michael also tells me: "appdetail has a bunch more, you can get the icon via the normal icon-theme mechanism, but you have to add /usr/share/app-install/icons to the iconpath via append_path()"

Answer (score 2):

Use the package [python-apt](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/python-apt) [image: Install python-apt], there are docs in `/usr/share/doc/python-apt`

For example to get a list of all installed packages use

```
import apt
cache = apt.Cache()
installed_packages = [p for p in cache if p.is_installed]
```

As the Software Centre is written in Python you may want to have a look at its source code as well.

Comment: Thanks, that works well. However, I'm still wondering if I could tap into the data shown in the Applications Lens. That would probably give me the app's icon and would return more relevant results (I believe the Lens shows only apps with a .desktop file, e.g. more user-centric software rather than libraries, CLI software, etc).

Comment: Have a look at the .desktop files in `/usr/share/app-install/desktop`